# MacOS pip install pyexr raised OpenEXR.cpp:37:10: fatal error: 'ImfIO.h' file not found

Tags: python, openexr

`pip install pyexr`

Then, it raised:

```
Collecting pyexr
  Using cached PyEXR-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: future in /Users/li/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyexr) (0.18.2)
Collecting OpenEXR
  Using cached OpenEXR-1.3.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/li/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyexr) (1.19.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: OpenEXR
  Building wheel for OpenEXR (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/li/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5_/r_bbpkqj2t126yjr97zgbvshnb19df/T/pip-install-c9hgqbad/openexr_2e771c75afb74b589da0413a0d9f26e0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5_/r_bbpkqj2t126yjr97zgbvshnb19df/T/pip-install-c9hgqbad/openexr_2e771c75afb74b589da0413a0d9f26e0/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/5_/r_bbpkqj2t126yjr97zgbvshnb19df/T/pip-wheel-ur0lkk8c
       cwd: /private/var/folders/5_/r_bbpkqj2t126yjr97zgbvshnb19df/T/pip-install-c9hgqbad/openexr_2e771c75afb74b589da0413a0d9f26e0/
  Complete output (15 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  copying Imath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  running build_ext
  building 'OpenEXR' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/li/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/li/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/include/OpenEXR -I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR -I/opt/local/include/OpenEXR -I/Users/li/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c OpenEXR.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/OpenEXR.o -g -DVERSION="1.3.2"
  OpenEXR.cpp:37:10: fatal error: 'ImfIO.h' file not found
  #include <ImfIO.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for OpenEXR
  Running setup.py clean for OpenEXR
Failed to build OpenEXR
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by:

```
brew install openexr
pip install git+https://github.com/jamesbowman/openexrpython.git
pip install pyexr
```

Comment: I needed a few more steps as detailed on this [link](https://github.com/jamesbowman/openexrpython/issues/44#issuecomment-1305799651):